tailwind width not workin
in the below image there is one navbar on that navber there is one card on which i want to increase the width of that card so that i looks like EXPECTED OUTCOME image
Code Output Image
<div className=" z-10 bg-blue-100  ">
        <div className=" z-23  flex flex-row justify-center items-center h-10">
          <div className=" -translate-y-32 z-30">
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center mt-8 px-4 lg:px-6">
              <div className="sm:mx-auto lg:mx-20 sm:text-center">
                <div className="  w-full  mx-auto  p-2">
                  <div className="flex flex-col mt-32 sm:mt-20 sm:flex-row md:flex-row lg:flex-row  items-center shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-white ">
                    {/* <!-- Image Div --> */}
                    <div className="">
                      <Image
                        src="MainFooter.svg"
                        alt="Image"
                        width={360}
                        height={100}
                      />
                    </div>
                    {/* <!-- Content Div --> */}
                    <div className="px-8 py-6 text-left">
                      <h2 className="mb-2 text-2xl sm:text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl text-gray-700 leading-relaxed font-extrabold">
                        Stay Updated With <br /> Financial Compliance
                      </h2>
                      <p className="mt-4 mb-6 max-w-md text-sm sm:text-base text-gray-700 font-light">
                        Subscribe to our newsletter for compliance updates and
                        tips
                      </p>
                      <form action="#" className="mb-4">
                        <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:justify-start">
                          <input
                            className="block w-full sm:w-auto mb-2 sm:mb-0 sm:mr-2 px-4 py-3 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-md border border-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500"
                            type="email"
                            placeholder="Enter email here"
                            required
                          />
                          <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="py-3 px-6 ml-2 mt-2 sm:mt-0 text-sm font-medium text-white rounded-md bg-orange-500 border border-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-300"
                          >
                            Get Updates
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>

EXPECTED OUTCOME
i want my navbar card width as shown in the above image but i am not able to achieve it

Hi Hussain, it seems to me that navbar card width is doing what you want. If not, kindly give a specific description of what the issue is.

I'm not sure what the issue is here, the container width seems to be working fine. I can give you some hints:

'flex-row' is default for flex-direction, so you don't need to specify that (unlesse you've set flex-col as default on config file).
If you set a breakpoint, it's works like a min-width breakpoint. For example, there's no need to set "flex-col sm:flex-row md:flex-row lg:flex-row" you can just write "flex-col sm:flex-row" and it'll work for medium and large screens as well. (link to docs)
To get that image overflowing like the desired outcome you can add "relative" class to container div, "absolute left-0 bottom-0" to the image div and add another div with the same width as the image just to widen the container, something like this:


<div className="flex mt-32 sm:mt-20 items-center shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-white text-black relative">
  {/* <!-- this div just widens the container--> */}
  <div className="w-[360px]"></div>
  {/* <!-- Image Div with absolute position--> */}
  <div className="absolute left-0 bottom-0">
    <img src={pic} alt="Image" width={360} height={100} />
  </div>
  {/* <!-- Content Div --> */}
</div>


